# I can't run Ubuntu 13.10 on my galaxy pocket

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

I have a galaxy pocket and I want to run Ubuntu 13.10 but when I try to start using Linux complete installer here is what I get:

```
$ cd /sdcard/ubuntu
$ su
# s/bootscript.sh /sdcard/ubuntu/ubuntu-13.10.CORE.ext2.img
Checking loop device... FOUND
No user defined mount points
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
Shutting down Linux ARM
umount: can't umount /data/local/mnt/dev: Invalid argument
# losetup: /dev/block/loop255: No such device or address
```